What features to look for when buying a microscope?
I have been looking at different microscopes for soldering, specifically for micro-soldering (SMDs). I have seen the dinky USB microscopes, the smaller pedestal-type with small screens, units mounted to an articulating arm, and the larger binocular/trinocular models.
As a beginner with SMDs and on a student budget (not an Electronics major), what features (at a bare minimum) should I be looking for in a microscope?
Note: I would like to connect to an external monitor for supplemental viewing, but if not possible at a lower budget it won't be a deal-breaker. I would be using both a soldering iron and a hot air tool (I have most of the tools just looking at expanding with a microscope).

Can't you use the microscopes they have at your school? Also, I'd rather look through the microscope while I'm soldering, not an external monitor. That way, you can see where your hands are at all time. That soldering iron is very hot so the last thing I'd want to do is lose track of where my hands are and burn myself.

Are you planning on using a soldering iron, air tool, or both? Our microscope has about a 16 cm (6.2") working distance with about a 10X zoom. The distance is fine for the iron, but the air tool needs to come in at an angle, and tends to blow small components away. More zoom would be better. M0402 (01005) components still look tiny.

Consider your overall budget for solder iron, tools, fume extractor, microscope, other stuff. You should probably prioritize them in that order.

"connect to an external monitor for supplemental viewing" Unless you're teaching, I've found this to be of little practical use.  I'd suggest an optical stereo scope, on a sliding arm.  What is your budget?

@Lundin Depending on what the OP is working on, I'd give a microscope a higher priority (the same as "tools") if they need to work with SMD components on a regular basis. Sure, 0402 and 0603 resistors are big enough for the naked eyes, but it's another matter if one needs to solder/inspect a PCB prototype with hundreds of them...

@ChrisKnudsen While I see your concern, it is a personal preference, and have the hand-eye coordination to be able to accomplish the task (I have done graphic design with a graphics tablet).

@Colin I am not enrolled in any electronics classes, this is a side hobby for me but I do have some of the tools already.

@C.Dunn Both. This is what I need to know, what zoom would be the minimum to get?

@比尔盖子 This is more side hobby for now, so it's not a daily task of SMD soldering. My eyesight is not the best hence the need for a microscope.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@agarza the level of zoom depends on the smallest component you plan on soldering, and how poor your eyesight is. 10X is more than enough for M1005 (0402) resistors and my eyesight is pretty bad. I've also soldered using magnifying glasses and workstation magnifiers. They are cheaper than a microscope, but the drawback is usually less working distance.

@C.Dunn I have a magnifying lamp with 8X and I believe it was a 0402 resistor that I was desoldering on a throwaway board. Yes, not a lot of working distance but I was able to see it well enough. This helps a lot, thanks.

@比尔盖子 I guess it depends on what you want to destroy first, your eye sight or your lungs... :) I used to solder down to 0402 with naked eye no problem, but as we age that turns increasingly difficult. Also what seemed to be a nice joint with the naked eye could turn out to be a bad one when peeking at it in the microscope indeed. Students are usually young, so eye sight may be less of a problem. Breathing in flux fumes is bad for everyone no matter age, however.

Presumably you have tried a microscope at university or work or something. If you like it, get that exact one. If you can't afford it, look at the specs and try to find a comparable but cheaper model. I have a cheap AmScope SM-1BSX-64S and I think it's great.
Another, worse strategy would be to just look on an e-commerce site where you trust the reviews and find one that people review well for SMD work. That's what I would do if I absolutely could not find a microscope to try.
I've used a few different scopes at various work places, and here's some features that I find are important:

Stereo vision gives you depth perception. That will be very helpful. You won't get that with a video monitor.
Get a ring illuminator, every other type I've used is worse, and they're cheap.
Note the working distance. Scopes vary a lot on this. I just measured mine and it approximately 11cm from the lowest point on the head assembly to the focal point. The ring light takes up 3cm of that. I find that to be enough. The ad for my scope says 20cm, so I'm not sure how they calculate it. Maybe it's with the optional barlow lens? I personally never use that.
With 10x eyepieces, my scope has a zoom of 7-45x. You could go slightly higher, but I think that's about perfect even for 0201 and 0.5mm pitch parts.

A few tips:

Sometimes you will want to work over the table instead of the
microscope base. A quick and easy way to do that is to just put a heavy weight on the base and then swivel it around to the back or side. I keep a 25x100x100mm steel block on my bench for this purpose.

A plastic table will melt easily. Keep a small metal plate handy for when you need to solder close to the table.

I 3D printed a jig that can hold PCBs at a 30degree angle. Sometimes useful for working on the sides of parts that don't have legs, like QFN.

When someone in my family gets a foot splinter, I put the scope on the coffee table and have them lay on the couch with their foot under the scope. You can get any splinter out this way nearly painlessly. Make sure you use clean tools.


